# How to implement language setting in android app?

Tags: java, android, settings

I am working on an android app. In this application, I need to provide several languages to people that live in different countries. How to implement language setting in android app?

EDIT: I made the setting UI that added several languages into it. I need to know how to save the language selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to internationalize Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733874/how-to-internationalize-android-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Shared Preference, declare it in your onCreate Method.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Read the `String` variable in onCreate method.

```
String language = sharedPref.getString("language", "english");
```

Save the `String` variable that stores the language.

```
String language = "english";

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("language", language);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new resource folder called `values-` followed by the lang suffix :

```
/res
    values/
        string.xml
    values-fr/
        string.xml
```

in the new `string.xml` file, translate all the resources (without changing the key of each value of course). The phone will then automatically pick the right file according to the user's phone current language.